# How do I search for a string read from a .csv file in a dataset with some extra words in the string in R language?

Tags: r, string, string-comparison, string-matching, string-search

I want to match the string from a dataset i.e. Indian Inst Technol, Dept Mech & Ind Engn, Roorkee; to INDIAN INST TECHNOL ROORKEE which is read from a .CSV file. How do I match it correspondingly and increment the IIT Roorkee counter?

Edit I tried

```
str="INDIAN INST TECHNOL ROORKEE"
strm="Indian Inst Technol, Dept Mech & Ind Engn, Roorkee;"
grep(str, strm, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = FALSE, value = FALSE, fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)
```

But it returned 0

Edit 2- I just want to match the strings before ';' semicolon is reached in the strm. The only problem is to allow some words in between and still getting a true!

Comment: have you tried grep or one of its variants?

Comment: Please post a code example of what you have tried.

Comment: >str="INDIAN INST TECHNOL ROORKEE"
> strm="Indian Inst Technol, Dept Mech & Ind Engn, Roorkee;"
> 
> 
> grep(str, strm, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = FALSE, value = FALSE, fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)